# ¿Por qué se suspende mi código js al ejecutar el evento click en Livewire en Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewire

Estoy en un proyecto en Laravel 8 pero tengo un problema en una de las vistas.

Estoy usando también Livewire para la reactividad, por ejemplo en la vista de payment he creado un formulario multipaso o multi-step que cuando doy click en el botón continuar me lleva al siguiente step de la misma vista con el evento wire:click='metodo', ejemplo:

```
<button wire:click='nextPage'>
    Continuar
</button>
```

nextPage() es el método que me lleva al siguiente step, al ejecutar este evento todo muy bien me lleva al step siguiente con toda normalidad, pero el problema radica en que se deshabilita todos los eventos javascript que están en un script en mi layout `app.blade.php`, esto pasa al momento de dar el primer click y desencadenar el evento wire:click.

En mi `app.blade.php` estoy usando un file js de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src="{{ asset(js/index.js) }}" defer></script>
```

Necesito ayuda con esto, muchas gracias de ante mano!!

Comment: Inspecciona la consola del navegador, normalmente cuando deja de funcionar todo el JS es que has tenido un error antes.

Comment: No lo creo, porque el código del file js funciona muy bien, pero después del click evento de livewire es que se suspende todo el file js! Al inspeccionar la consola me aparece que no caraga ese file js!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- En tu componente en el método donde aplicas el evento con el wire:click colocas esto:

  `$this->emit('reloadClassCSs');`
- Luego en tu plantilla base en donde jalas los JS obtienes el método enviado así:

  `<script> window.livewire.on('reloadClassCSs', function() { //aqui pones tu codigo js que necesita tu componente o el js necesario en  si  }); </script>`

Con eso ya se soluciono mi problema pero puede que te ayude de la misma forma.

El problema esta en que cuando cambias a nextpage, se renderiza el nuevo contenido y el scripts que agrega las classes no vuelve a cargar, entonces lo que se necesitaba era volver a ejecutar el codigo que agrega las classes..
$this->emit  =>> emite un evento el cual puede ser capturado con javascripts desde el blade, le agregas el nombre al evento a ejecutar y desde el blade se captura ese evento.
Agrega el codigo y ya debera agregar las clases cada vez que cambies de nextpage.